# in kotlin, how to access protected static member in parent class from sub class

Tags: kotlin, static, protected

It is code worked in java but after convert to kotlin it does not compile.

Having a base class which has some defines as static protected member in the companion object:

```kotlin
abstract class ParentClass {

   companion object {
        @JvmField
        final protected val SERVICE_TYPE_A = "the_service_type_a"    
   }
}
```

and the child class:

```kotlin
class ChildClass: ParentClass {
    public override fun getServiceType(): String {
        return SERVICE_TYPE_A. //<== got compile error
    }
}
```

it does not compile.

how to access a parent class static protected member from subclass?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@JvmStatic` instead as follows:

```kotlin
abstract class ParentClass {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        protected val SERVICE_TYPE_A = "the_service_type_a"
    }

    abstract fun getServiceType(): String
}
```

The `final` keyword in `SERVICE_TYPE_A` is redundant since everything is `final` by default in Kotlin. This also mean that if you want `ParentClass` to be extended, then you need to explicitly define it as `open`.

Then your `ChildClass` would look as follows:

```kotlin
class ChildClass: ParentClass() {
    override fun getServiceType(): String {
        return SERVICE_TYPE_A
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems not working. the ParentClass is simplified sample (missed the open keyword), it is actually an abstracted class I updated the question.

Comment: Please avoid simplifying questions too much otherwise you get wrong answers. I've updated my answer according to the updated question. Please check it ;)

Comment: thanks for the help. using @JvmStatic makes it compilable, but also generates a `protected final String getSERVICE_TYPE_A()` in the java code, and get error `IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.xxx.ParentClass$Companion.getSERVICE_TYPE_A()` in where the `SERVICE_TYPE_A` is referred. It might need some refactoring to make it work (especially calling from java code).

Comment: But you didn't mention that this is supposed to be used within Java code. You mentioned that you were converting Java to Kotlin. I assumed all your code would be Kotlin then.